# Assembler Factorial 16 bits in https://parraman.github.io/asm-simulator/

Tags: assembly, factorial

Here's the problem statement in English:

"I have a problem with my 16-bit assembler code in the emulator for a Factorial Program:

```
JMP boot 
JMP isr     ; Interrupt vector
JMP svc     ; System call vector

sStackTop   EQU 0x0FF   ; Initial Supervisor SP
uStackTop   EQU 0x1FF   ; Initial User Task SP
txtDisplay  EQU 0x2E0

keypressed:     ; 1 = key pressed
    DB 0        ; 0 = No key pressed

value:          ; The number of the
    DB 0        ; key pressed in ASCII

boot:
    ; ... (Boot, isr, and svc code remains unchanged) ...

    ORG 0x100   ; Following instructions
                ; will be assembled at 0x100

task:           ; The user task
    MOV A, 0
    MOV B, 0
loop:
    CALL readchar   ; Polls the keypad
    CMPB AH, 1      ; using readchar
    JNZ loop
    MOVB BL, AL     ; If key was pressed use
    CALL factorial  ; calculate factorial
    JMP loop 

readchar:       ; User space wrapper
    ; ... (readchar and putchar code remains unchanged) ...

factorial:
    MOV CX, BL      ; Set the value for which to calculate factorial
    MOV AX, 1       ; Initialize the result to 1

    FACTORIAL_LOOP:
    MUL CX          ; Multiply AX by CX
    DEC CX          ; Decrement CX
    JNZ FACTORIAL_LOOP  ; Jump to FACTORIAL_LOOP if CX is not zero

    MOVB BL, AL     ; Move the result to BL register
    CALL putchar    ; print the result
    RET  ; Error 38: Error: MOV does not support these operands
```

I have tried everything but it's not working. The idea is to capture the number, calculate its factorial, and display it in the output."

The error message is "Error: MOV does not support these operands."

this is link https://parraman.github.io/asm-simulator/

I tried to modify the MOV instruction in the factorial subroutine to move the result to the BL register, which is a byte-sized register, using MOVB BL, AL. However, the assembler returned an error "Error: MOV does not support these operands" indicating that the assembler does not support moving data between byte-sized and word-sized registers directly with the MOV instruction.

What I was expecting was that the MOVB BL, AL instruction would move the lower byte of the AX register (which contains the factorial result) into the BL register, allowing me to print the result using the putchar subroutine.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8vty.png)

Comment: Note that the error is on line 38: `MOV CX, BL`. You can't move a 8 bit register into a 16 bit one (and even then `CX` should be `C`)

Comment: "I tried in various ways in 16-bit format but couldn't achieve it. Perhaps you could give me an example or a solution to the error in the simulator?"

Comment: Your source code is for 16-bit x86, but that simulator appears to be a different ISA.  It only has registers A, B, C, D, and special registers IP, SSP / USP (stack pointers?), and SR (status register).  And valid x86 instructions like `mov cx, bx` and `mov cl, bl` don't assemble with it.  (Intel syntax doesn't use size suffixes like `movb` for byte move, and even AT&T syntax doesn't require them.)

Comment: It's unclear what you want to do but `MOV C, B` assembles. You probably need to get rid of all the other `X` as well. Your program might still be broken though.

Comment: The simulator menu has a link to its docs: https://asm-simulator.readthedocs.io/en/latest/instruction-set.html .  It seems to be inspired by x86, having AH/AL and so on, but lacking SI, DI, and BP.  And the full 16-bit registers are just named A,B,C,D as shown in the debugger window.  And yeah, it has separate mnemonics for byte operand-size.  Anyway, to move with zero-extension, `xor C,C` / `movb CL, BL`.  Or `movb ch, 0` / `movb cl, bl`, those might be the same length in machine code.

Comment: I want to calculate the factorial of a number in 16-bit assembler using the following simulator. https://parraman.github.io/asm-simulator/ with instrucions https://asm-simulator.readthedocs.io/en/latest/instruction-set.html#instruction-mov

Comment: Is there a way you can guide me or explain how to achieve the result I expect in that simulator?